# The sort method didn't work. Latest Laravel 8.12

Tags: laravel

**The sort method didn't work. Latest Laravel 8.12**

```
$array = ['Desk', 'Table', 'Chair'];
$sorted = Arr::sort($array);
return $sorted;
```

**The result**

```
{
"0": "Desk",
"1": "Table",
"2": "Chair"
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOSK8.png)

Comment: i have checked in laravel 8.4 and it return as expected .{"2":"Chair","0":"Desk","1":"Table"}

Comment: it keeps the keys but sorts by the values, seems something is reordering by the keys when you are viewing it, as `dump($sorted)` and `json_encode($sorted)` look correct on 8.13

Comment: Sorry This problem is from Json Formatter ( Chrome extension )

Comment: if you want to reset the keys you can call `array_values` ... `return array_values($sorted);`

Comment: @lagbox.perfect catch.seems op as same issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry This problem is from Json Formatter ( Chrome extension )